# How do I center text vertically and horizontally over image with percentage width and height?

Tags: html, css, css-position, centering

I've been trying to center my text over a div with a percentage width and height. I tried using flexbox but that didn't work out for me so I used this tutorial as a reference: http://jsfiddle.net/4be9cp23/.
Here's the code from this tutorial:

html

```
<div id="header">
        <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
        background-color: red;  
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%; 
        height: 15%;
    }
#header h1{ display:inline-block; }
```

Here's a link to the demo that I'm working on http://codepen.io/maureenv/pen/dMEPap?editors=1100. I want the white text to be centered over the image of the dragon (without having the text in the form-container class below it move):

I followed the above tutorial and tried: 
HTML

```
 <div class="masthead-container">
      <img src="http://maureenvogel.com/images/charizard.jpg" class="masthead-img">

      <div class="quote-container">
        <div class="quote"> "This is my quote that won't center no matter what I do. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. " </div>
        <div class="quote-author"> -quote by me</div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- close masthead container div -->
```

CSS

```
.masthead-container .masthead-img{
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.masthead-container {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.masthead-container .quote-container{
  display: inline-block;
}

.quote-container{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However, the text refuses to center and display-inline block isn't working for me. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You could set the img to a background-img, then look into display : table; or flex. https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.quote-container{
  top: 50%;
  left:  50%;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could try to put your img on background of the div, and make :

```css
.masthead-container{
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   background: url:(...);
}

.text-to-center{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="masthead-container">
  <div class="text-to-center"><p>hello-world</p></div>
</div>
```